# Running "Graphviz" viz.js from Java 8 Nashorn Engine

Tags: javascript, java, java-8, graphviz, nashorn

I'm trying to render graphviz from Java 8 (Nashorn engine) on the server, but I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "Promise" is not defined in <eval> at line number 120
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:455)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:387)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeMethod(NashornScriptEngine.java:196)
    at test1.VizDemo.main(VizDemo.java:24)
Caused by: <eval>:120 ReferenceError: "Promise" is not defined
```

This is my (simple) program so far:

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.script.Invocable;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

public class VizDemo {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

    engine.eval(new InputStreamReader(VizDemo.class.getResourceAsStream(
      "./viz.js")));
    engine.eval(new InputStreamReader(VizDemo.class.getResourceAsStream(
      "./full.render.js")));

    Object v = engine.eval("new Viz();");
    System.out.println("v=" + v);

    if (engine instanceof Invocable) {
      Invocable invEngine = (Invocable) engine;
      Object result = invEngine.invokeMethod(v, "renderSVGElement",
          "digraph { a -> b; a -> c; }");
      System.out.println("result=" + result);
    }
  }

}
```

What am I missing? Or... is it actually possible to run Javascript in Java 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nashorn doesn't support `Promise`, you need to implement a "Pollyfill" to provide `Promise` support. Here is an implementation: https://github.com/shendepu/nashorn-polyfill